# Создание модального диалога

Tags: java, swing

Работаю над игрой,и в процессе создания главного меню,столкнулся с проблемой:

Имеется панель MMenu,на которой находится кнопка Exit. По нажатию на Exit должна выводиться панель CheckExit (которая так же размещена на панели MMenu) (CheckExit представляет собой проверку выхода из программы,в виде 2 кнопок "Назад" и "Выход").

CheckExit небольшого размера, и не перекрывает полностью все элементы панели MMenu,что позволяет наводить и нажимать на кнопки панели MMenu, которые остались видны. При наведении, кнопки с панели MMenu перекрывают панель CheckExit.

Вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы панель CheckExit со своим содержимым, выводилась поверх всех элементов, и никаким образом не перекрывалась другими элементами панели MMenu?

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо использовать JDialog или JOptionPane

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
         "Хотите выйти?", "Вы действительно хотите выйти из игры?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

Comment: Это является решением моей текущей проблемы,но не является ответом на поставленный вопрос. В дальнейшем,я планирую использовать наложение одних элементов на другие,и мне хотелось бы разобраться с позиционированием элементов в Swing.

Comment: Тогда вам надо переформулировать вопрос

Comment: Переформулировал. Теперь более ясно,что я хочу узнать?

Comment: @TrueASL Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.